# Can I develop OpenGL based applications using C#

Tags: opengl

Can I develop OpenGL based applications using C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can.  The [Tao Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao_Framework) used to be the recommended C# OpenGL + lots-of-other-crap set of bindings, but nowadays most people use [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) since it is more actively maintained.

I have implemented [a music visualizer in pure C#](http://picasaweb.google.com/cdhowie/OpenVPScreenshots) using Tao, so it's definitely possible to do cool stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [CSGL project](http://csgl.sourceforge.net/).